# Emissivity of vacuum for radiation heat

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, optical-materials

What is the heat radiation emissivity of vacuum? For air as well? What is the difference?

I understand that the vacuum has reflectivity of 0, So what is the other two values are in
$$
reflectivity + emissivity + transmission =1. 
$$
And how this can be different for Air?

Comment: all matter above 0 K emits radiation. In a perfect vacuum, where there is no matter, there is nothing to emit radiation.  The emissivity of gases in the atmosphere (mostly air) is apparently 0.83 http://atlantic.evsc.virginia.edu/~bph/AW_Book_Spring_96/AW_Book_21.html . They are different because air is not the same as no matter.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the heat radiation emissivity of vacuum?

**None.** Or better yet: **undefined**.

Emissivity happens from a matter of non-zero temperature. Vacuum is not just cold matter - vacuum is *no matter*.

> For air as well? What is the difference?

The difference is that air is particles containing energy. They can emit this energy at a non-zero temperature. Vacuum is just a word for... nothing. The emissivity of air I do not know by heart, but might be found in proporty tables. (I can see it is mentioned with a link in the comments by @pentane. This seems to be considering water vapour and other content in the air, so this value will vary a lot according to the content of the air.)

> I understand that the vacuum has reflectivity of 0, So what is the other two values are in $reflectivity+emissivity+transmission=1$

Reflectivity is zero, there is no emissivity and the transmission would therefor be $1$ (vacuum lets 100% of radiation through).

> And how this can be different for Air?

Some radiation hitting the molecules of air will be reflected (sent back or redirected, but *not* absorbed or passing through). Reflectivity will be non-zero but very small. Emissivity has a value, as mentioned above. Everything that is not *reflected* or absorbed and re*emitted* is *transmitted*. The equation is equal to $1$, corresponding to 100%, since these three factors include all possibilities. They will each take up a portion of the entire radiation, which in total of course is 100%.